# Dynamically hiding some menuitems from GWT UiBinder java

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Is there a way to dynamically hide some menuitems from the UiBinder.java in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

UIBinder is used to initialize. As far as my knowledge goes, it is not possible to insert conditional logic in the xml. Hiding items programatically is the way to go.